# Entity Framework not shown in nuget packet manager in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nuget, nuget-package

I started to learn Entity Framework. I created a console application in Visual Studio 2019 and I try to install Entity Framework from Nuget Package Manager:

[image: Screenshot of nuget package]*
[image]
[image]

but Entity Framework is not showing up in the Nuget Browse Tab...

Can you please give me a solution how to install Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Does the `Package Source` at the top right contain `NuGet`? Did you delete the NuGet source by accident perhaps?

Comment: @pune: In the Visual Studio go to **_Tools > Options... > NuGet Package Manager_**.   Check that the _Package sources_ has reference to [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json)

Comment: @Jackdaw, There is no reference of  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in package source. How i reference to  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json this ?

Comment: @pune: The _Package sources_ usually set like on the following screenshot: [Package sources](https://i.imgur.com/Z4SRJsR.png)

Comment: @Jackdaw,I uploade one more screenshot in question, pls see, i add https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in package source, till not show Entity Framework in nuget package manager

Comment: @pune: Use **_Up_** button to move the  _api.nuget.org/v3/index.json_ source to the first line. On your screenshot it at the third line. Or you can use  `Package Source` combo box in the _Manage  Packages for Solution..._ dialog  to select the current [Package source](https://i.imgur.com/Rk7mHHU.png). On your screen-shot as you can see it set to **_Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages_**  this why you list does not refreshing.

Comment: @Jackdaw, I move up api.nuget.org/v3/index.json to top but till not working, How i use Package Source combo box i not understand. There other solution available ? i really want to install Entity Framework through Nuget package manager. Please Please give me solution please

Comment: @Jackdaw, Is  Any other solution available ?

Comment: @pune: Did you select `NuGet Online` in the `Package Source` combo box on the _Manage Packages for Solution..._ dialog? Described above is the best solution.

Comment: @Jackdaw,I select but not work,i try to select nuget.org but there is no option of nuget.org... There only show two options Packages.config and PackageReference...not showing nuget.org

Comment: @pune: There is no option `nuget.org` because on my screen-shot it was, but on you dialog it changed to `NuGet Online`. Doesn't matter. Select `NuGet Online` in the `Package Source` combo box on the `Manage Packages for Solution...` dialog and try to search for required packages.

Comment: @pune: The latest screenshot useless. Can you press `Cancel` on the `Options` dialog and that make a new screenshot without this dialog?

Comment: @Jackdaw :Ok i cancel screenshot,  I do all things, i select Nuget Online,Restart VS 2019 , but i not get Entity Framework package, You really helpful but i till not get solution,Thank you for your great help...pls give me solution of this . How i install Entity Framework package

Comment: @Jackdaw : Sir, I try to install Entity Framework using package manager console,,but above error occures pls see screenshot , i attached screenshot, and please help

Comment: @pune: All of the previous remarks were intended to describe you how to set packages sources correctly. According to you last screen-short you didn't set packages sources properly.  One more time. In the Visual Studio go to **Tools > Options... > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources**. And define **ONLY ONE** package source like on this screenshot: [Package Source Definition](https://i.imgur.com/Z4SRJsR.png)

Comment: @Jackdaw : I set only one package source and its working...Thank you so much Sir....After that its possible to install and i install entity framework through Package Manager Console......How i directly install Entity Framework through Nuget Package Manager?